# Python requests_html throwing error There is no current event loop in thread 'ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0'

Tags: python, django, python-asyncio, event-loop, python-requests-html

I am trying to run a `JS script` using **python requests_html module** for a given url but was getting few errors.

Can some please help me out?

**Code** :-

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
def rrr(request):
    session = HTMLSession()
    url = 'https://careers.microsoft.com/'
    response = session.get(url)
    script = """
                () => {
                    return {
                        ans: window.location.href,
                    }
                }
            """
    ans = response.html.render(script=script)
    return JsonResponse(ans, safe=False)
```

**Error :-**

```
  File "/home/mahesh/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 476, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/home/mahesh/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 502, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mahesh/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/decorators.py", line 50, in handler
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mahesh/Documents/dojo/dojo/dojo/tenants/api.py", line 242, in rrr
    ans = response.html.render(script=script)
  File "/home/mahesh/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests_html.py", line 586, in render
    self.browser = self.session.browser  # Automatically create a event loop and browser
  File "/home/mahesh/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests_html.py", line 727, in browser
    self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
  File "/home/mahesh/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/asyncio/events.py", line 644, in get_event_loop
    % threading.current_thread().name)
RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0'.
```

**When ran in terminal, it worked fine as follows**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How are you running RRR? asyncio is finicky in multithreaded application. Need more info

Comment: how are you running it on python?

Comment: I am trying to host this function as an api in my Django app and get the response

Comment: Not helpful. But I came across another question that gave the same error response. You don't have a running event loop in your main thread which was what I wanted to confirm with you.

Comment: Oh....so can you please tell me what else I need to add in this code to make it work?

Comment: Yes... It's the whole code which i posted in the question

Comment: where's your entry point?  how are you running the script?

Comment: Sorry I am not getting you..... As i previously mentioned i defined rrr in urls.py and trying to hit api via postman.... Please think the rrr function itself as a complete code block which is resided in my views.py file